# Query Formula excludes results with new line character

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

It seems there may be a bug in Google Sheets' Query formula where results with a new line character (char 10) are excluded when the column is filtered. Is there any way around this or am I doing something wrong?

[image: source data in columns A:C, query formula in E1 doesn't return rows 5 or 6 even though the filter criteria says they should.]

Comment: The Query in E1 should also be returning the values in A5:C6 as they meet the criteria: where B like '%2%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- this is not a fault of **`CHAR(10)`** nor bug
- by examining the whole range with **`=ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(A2:C7))`** you can see that **`CHAR(10)`** causes cells with numbers to act like **`TEXT`** which makes sense because there is not a number like **`19 68`** it's either **`19`**, **`68`** or **`1968`**

  [image]
- therefore, you will need to use such query that works with text not with numbers:

  ```
  =QUERY(A1:C7, "select A,B,C where B contains '2'")
  ```

  [image]

Comment: very interesting... the project I was working on had the issue on cells with text but using contains seems to have fixed it! Thanks!